# Node spawn process and store output

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, ntfs, spawn

This part of my script is trying to spawn a child that is going to clone a hard drive. It basically works but the issue that I am having is that when I encounter an error and want to store the output, it only stores the first line of the output, excluding the things that I actually need. I have run the command outside of the script and it gives me two lines of output, with the second line being the error if it fails. So, how could I store the entire output. Help is much appreciated, thank you!

```
NtfsPartition.prototype.WriteFs = function(filename, progress, success, error) {
    console.log('Writing NTFS FS');
    var s = spawn("ntfsclone", ['--restore-image', '--overwrite', this.dev, filename]);
    var err_msg = '';
    s.on('error', function(err) {
        err_msg = err;
    });
    s.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
        err_msg += data.toString();
    });
    s.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        var match = data.toString().match(kNtfsWriteFsProgressRegex);
        if(!match) {
            return;
        }
        progress(match[1]);
    });
    s.on('exit', function(code) {
        if(code != 0) {
            console.log(err_msg);
            return error('Error: ' + code + ' - ' + err_msg);
        }
        success();
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a great first question, and we look forward to your further contributions to the community. I just added a few tags to make your question easier to find, and for future reference, you can indent large blocks of code with 4 spaces, rather than using the inline backticks. Those are very minor details though, and I'm sure a quick visit to the [help] will teach you some other nice tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, I can't actually test this, but I suspect that removing the `s.stderr.on('data', ...)` handler will allow you to ensure that `err_msg` is an `Error` object.

Also taking note of [this warning](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_error):

> *Note*: The `'exit'` event may or may not fire after an error has occurred. When listening to both the `'exit'` and `'error'` events, it is important to guard against accidentally invoking handler functions multiple times.

I could see a possible solution looking like this:

```
NtfsPartition.prototype.WriteFs = function(filename, progress, success, error) {
    console.log('Writing NTFS FS');
    var s = spawn("ntfsclone", ['--restore-image', '--overwrite', this.dev, filename]);
    var errors = [];
    // if possible, might get multiple of these
    // if not, this still works for a single error
    s.on('error', function(err) {
        errors.push(err)
    });
    s.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        var match = data.toString().match(kNtfsWriteFsProgressRegex);
        if(!match) {
            return;
        }
        progress(match[1]);
    });
    // guaranteed to be called, whereas 'exit' is not(?)
    s.on('close', function(code) {
        if(code != 0) {
            var stacks = errors.map(function (err) {
              return err.stack;
            });
            // all the errors
            return error('Error: ' + code + '\n\n' + stacks.join('\n\n'))
        }
        success();
    });
}
```

One of the keys is to use the [`error.stack`](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_error_stack) property, since errors typically tend to log the [`message`](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_error_message) property instead by default, when coerced to a string. This property is probably the single-line feedback you were getting in your code, since you never checked the `err_msg.stack`.

Comment: Hi, yup removing s.stderr.on did the trick! Thanks for the help much appreciated

Comment: No problem, glad I could help